# Finding a projection matrix onto the $xz$-plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

I'm having some trouble with the following linear algebra question:

Projecting onto the $xz$-plane or the $yz$-plane can easily be performed through rotations. For instance, if you want to project onto the $xz$-plane,you need to rotate the $y$-axis to the $z$-axis (this is a rotation about the $x$-axis), then perform the projection, and rotate back. Write down the projection matrix which does just this.

---

So I'm pretty sure that the answer will be the product of $3$ matrices? Since we want to project on the $xz$-plane, we want to rotate about the $y$-axis around the $x$-axis to the $z$-axis.

I've tried for several hours, but I cannot come up with much. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't a projection onto the $xz$-plane simply changing the $y$-component to zero? i.e. $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x, 0, z)$? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, but I also need to rotate the $y$-axis to the $z$-axis before I perform the projection (and then rotate it back afterward), right? I'm having trouble coming up with a matrix that performs this task.

Comment: The process you have described doesn't provide a projection onto $xz$-plane...

Comment: If we want to project onto the $xz$-plane, we can first rotate the $y$-axis to the $z$-axis (which is a rotation around the $x$-axis), then project, and rotate back. I need to find a matrix that performs this.

Answer (score 3):

A projection matrix onto $xz$ plane is simply given by

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

indeed for any $v=(a,b,c)$ we have

$$Pv=(a,0,c)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one final question -- how can I use this matrix to project a point (say, (1, 2, 3)) with a center of perspective defined for $y$? (say, $y = 10$). I've been nonstop reading wikipedia pages, and I can't get anything...

Comment: wait, I'm not sure if the matrix is supposed to be that simple. shouldn't it be a product of three matrices? this is a  perspective projection in which the rays formed aren't all parallel

Comment: @blackmoon2031 Ah ok you are looking for a [Perspective_projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) problem.

Comment: do you know how to help me please? I have been struggling for very long